# How to put an "arbitrary" operation into a sliding window using Theano?

Tags: python, theano, convolution, sliding-window

I want to define some function on a matrix `X`. For example `mean(pow(X - X0, 2))`, where `X0` is another matrix (`X0` is fixed / constant). To make it more specific, let's assume that both `X` and `X0` are `10 x 10` matrices. The result of the operation is a real number.

Now I have a big matrix (let's say `500 x 500`). I want to apply the operation defined above to all `10 x 10` sub-matrices of the "big" matrix. In other words, I want to slide the `10 x 10` window over the "big" matrix. For each location of the window, I should get a real number. So, as a final result, I need to get a real-valued matrix (or 2D tensor) (its shape should be `491 x 491`).

What I want to have is close to a convolutional layer but not exactly the same because I want to use a mean squared deviation instead of a linear function represented by a neuron.

Comment: Just checking, is a pure-numpy/scipy solution acceptable? (Not that I have one in mind) Or do you expect a solution that uses Theano? P.S. typo: "...`X` and `X0` **are** `10 x 10`matrices."

Comment: @DavidZ, a pure-numpy/scipy solution would be acceptable. Actually I first  have tried to find a solution using numpy and it looks to me that there are no "native" ways to do it in numpy (although I am not sure about that). I thought that it might be more natural to do it in Theano since it provides convolutional layers (and what I want to do is similar to convolution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a Numpy solution, hope it suffices. 
I assume that your function is made up of an operation on the matrix elements and of a mean, i.e. a scaled sum. Hence, it is sufficient to look at `Y` as in

```
Y = np.power(X-X0, 2)
```

So we only need to deal with determining a windowed mean. Note that for the 1D case the matrix product with an appropriate vector of ones can be determined for calculating the mean, e.g.

```
h = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])  # same dimension as y
m1 = np.dot(h, y) / 2 
m2 = (y[1] + y[2]) / 2
print(m1 == m2)  # True
```

The 2D case is analogous, but with two matrix multiplications, one for the rows and one for the columns. E.g.

```
m_2 = np.dot(np.dot(h, Y), h) / 2**2
```

To construct a sliding window, we need to build a matrix of shifted windows, e.g.

```
H = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, ..., 0],
            .
            .
            .
     [0, ..., 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

to calculate all the sums

```
S = np.dot(np.dot(H, Y), H.T)
```

A full example for a `(n, n)` matrix with a `(m, m)` window would be

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 500, 10
X0 = np.ones((n, n))
X = np.random.rand(n, n)
Y = np.power(X-X0, 2)

h = np.concatenate((np.ones(m), np.zeros(n-m)))  # window at position 0
H = np.vstack((np.roll(h, k) for k in range(n+1-m)))  # slide the window 
M = np.dot(np.dot(H,Y), H.T) / m**2  # calculate the mean
print(M.shape)  # (491, 491)
```

An alternative but probably slightly less efficient way for building `H` is

```
H = np.sum(np.diag(np.ones(n-k), k)[:-m+1, :] for k in range(m))
```

**Update**

Calculating the mean squared deviation is also possible with that approach. For that, we generalize the vector identity `|x-x0|^2 = (x-x0).T (x-x0) = x.T x - 2 x0.T x + x0.T x0` (a space denotes a scalar or matrix multiplication and `.T` a transposed vector) to the matrix case:

We assume `W` is a `(m,n)` matrix containing a block `(m.m)` identity matrix, which is able to extract the `(k0,k1)`-th `(m,m)` sub-matrix by `Y = W Z W.T`, where `Z` is the `(n,n)` matrix containing the data. Calculating the difference

```
 D = Y - X0 = Y = W Z W.T - X0
```

is straightforward, where `X0` and `D` is a `(m,m)` matrix. The square-root of the squared sum of the elements is called [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm). Based on those [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), we can write the squared sum as

```
s = sum_{i,j} D_{i,j}^2 = trace(D.T D) = trace((W Z W.T - X0).T (H Z H.T - X0))
  = trace(W Z.T W.T W Z W.T) - 2 trace(X0.T W Z W.T) + trace(X0.T X0)
  =: Y0 + Y1 + Y2
```

The term `Y0` can be interpreted as `H Z H.T` from the method from above.The term `Y1` can be interpreted as a weighted mean on `Z` and `Y2` is a constant, which only needs to be determined once.
Thus, a possible implementation would be:

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 500, 10
x0 = np.ones(m)
Z = np.random.rand(n, n)

Y0 = Z**2
h0 = np.concatenate((np.ones(m), np.zeros(n-m)))
H0 = np.vstack((np.roll(h0, k) for k in range(n+1-m)))
M0 = np.dot(np.dot(H0, Y0), H0.T)

h1 = np.concatenate((-2*x0, np.zeros(n-m)))
H1 = np.vstack((np.roll(h1, k) for k in range(n+1-m)))
M1 = np.dot(np.dot(H1, Z), H0.T)

Y2 = np.dot(x0, x0)
M = (M0 + M1) / m**2 + Y2
```

Comment: your solution gives me an elegant way to calculate a "windowed" average (and also a weighted version of it). However, I do not think that it is exactly what I need. The problem is that in my window I have a "template" that I subtract from the underlying image, then I rise the result to power 2 and only then I calculate the average. In other words, X0 is not `(n,n)` it is `(m,m)`. X0 has the same size as the window and not as the original "big" image.

Comment: @Roman Overlooked that - updated the answer with a method for calculating the mean squared deviation.